# Detecting integral overflow with scanf

Tags: c, language-lawyer, iso

When recently [answering another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007310/need-explanation-for-c-program-output/28007340#28007340), I discovered a problem with code like:

```
int n;
scanf ("%d", &n);
```

With `strtol`, you can detect overflow because, in that case, the maximum value allowed is inserted into `n` and `errno` is set to indicate the overflow, as per `C11 7.22.1.4 The strtol, strtoll, strtoul, and strtoull functions /8`:

> If the correct value is outside the range of representable values, LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX, LLONG_MIN, LLONG_MAX, ULONG_MAX, or ULLONG_MAX is returned (according to the return type and sign of the value, if any), and the value of the macro ERANGE is stored in errno.

However, in the sections of the standard dealing with `scanf`, specifically `C11 7.21.6.2 The fscanf function /10`, we see:

> If this object does not have an appropriate type, or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behavior is undefined.

Now, to me, that means *any* value can be returned and there's no mention of `errno` being set to anything. This came to light because the asker of the linked question above was entering `9,999,999,999` into a 32-bit `int` and getting back `1,410,065,407`, a value `233` too small, indicating it had simply wrapped around at the limit of the type.

When *I* tried it, I got back `2,147,483,647`, the largest possible 32-bit unsigned value.

So my question is as follows. How do you detect integral overflow in a portable way when using the `scanf` family of functions? Is it even possible?

Now I should mention that, on my system (Debian 7), `errno` *is* actually set to `ERANGE` in these circumstances but I can find nothing in the *standard* that mandates this. Additionally, the return value from `scanf` is `1`, indicating success in scanning the item.

Comment: I can see one reason why `errno` does not work well here: `scanf` can have various conversions. Which of them does `errno` apply to? (If setting `errno` were equivalent to conversion failure, that would be unambiguous, but apparently that's not the case, not even in `strtol`.)

Comment: what is your system? you say _on my system `errno` ..._

Comment: @iharob: Debian 7,I'll update the question but I'm not really after an implementation-specific thing, rather one that's "kosher" according to the standard.

Comment: The FIRST thing you should do, is check the return value from scan -- it returns the number successful conversions. In your example if (scanf (..) != 1) you've got an error.

Comment: @Anonymouse: yes except, as stated in the last paragraph, it converts successfully even for the overflow case, it just doesn't give you the value entered. That's what I'm looking for, a portable solution where the return code indicates it succeeded and the errno is still zero, but the number overflowed.

Comment: What is the point of digging into this matter? stdio.h, and thus scanf, have always been good enough only for very basic input. While scanf may be fine for the classroom, or for simple number crunching applications, you can not safely depend on it for anything beyond that. If you want to protect the user from typing wrong data, control or function sequences, you must consider writing your own library and fetch the data from the input buffer.

Comment: Costis, yes, I've even written such things. But the _point_ is to get the question, which is not yet on SO, out there so that others may learn as well. It's certainly _possible_ that there may be a way, I dont use `scanf` enough to know for sure. But, even if there isn't (and that looks to be the case from the standard), that's still increasing the knowledge here.

Comment: The very fact that someone _asked_ the question I linked to means that a question asking if it's possible to do it portably could be useful.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Fair enough! It never hurts to dig and seek. I probably happen to be a little biased against stdio since back in the early 80's we had to spend days implementing alternate solutions for safe data input because of its deficiencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only portable way is to specify a field width, e.g. with `"%4d"` (guaranteed to even fit into a 16-bit `int`) or by building up the format string at run-time with a field width of `(int)(log(INT_MAX) / log(10))`. This of course also rejects for example 32000, although it would fit into a 16-bit `int`. So no, there is no satisfying portable way.

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html) don't specify more here, nor mention `ERANGE`.

[This manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) mentions setting `errno` only in case `EOF` is returned; [the glibc documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Formatted-Input) doesn't mention `ERANGE` at all.

That leaves the question what to suggest to beginners for reading integers, where I have no idea. `scanf` has too many undefined and underspecified aspects to be really useful, `fgets` cannot be used in productive code because you cannot handle 0-bytes properly, and portable error checking with `strtol` and friends takes more lines than implementing the functionality yourself (and is quite easy to get wrong). The behaviour of `atoi` is also undefined for integer overflow.